# Qt 4.6 QLineEdit Style. How do I style the gray highlight border so it's rounded?

Tags: qt, qt4, qlineedit

I'm styling a QLineEdit to have rounded borders for use as a search box. The rounding of the borders themselves were easy, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to round the highlighted portion of the widget when it has focus. I've tried QLineEdit::focus, but this only modifies the interior border. The images below show how the illusion of a rounded qlineedit is lost when it gains focus.

```
QListView, QLineEdit {
    color: rgb(127, 0, 63);
    selection-color: white;   
    border: 2px groove gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
QLineEdit:focus {
    color: rgb(127, 0, 63);
    selection-color: white;   
    border: 2px groove gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

QLineEdit:edit-focus {
    color: rgb(127, 0, 63);
    selection-color: white;   
    border: 2px groove gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

Images with and without focus:
[image: without]

[image: with]

Answer (score 5):

On the Mac:

```
widget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0);
```

should work, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987546/qt4-stylesheets-and-focus-rect/1990261#1990261). Otherwise you will have to subclass `QStyle` and remove the drawing of the focus rectangle there. See [Nokia FAQ 736 (How to avoid drawing focus rect)](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/faqs/736)

Answer (score -1):

Styling `QLineEdit:focus` appropriately should take care of your problem see [Qt Stylesheet Reference, List of Pseudo States](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states)

Comment: The pseudo state only effects the actual border, not the external border. It's possible I'm not using it appropriately. I've added my QLineEdit:focus and QLineEdit:edit-focus styles. The pics remain the same.

Comment: Yes you are right, this actually changes the style of the widget when the focus is on the widget, it does not affect the focus rect, adding a better answer, leaving this for reference