# How to prevent the default blue border being drawn on QLineEdit focus

Tags: qt, focus, border, qlineedit, qtstylesheets

I am trying to achieve a borderless QLineEdit through CSS. It works fine when the QLineEdit is not in focus but when in focus the default blue border always comes up. The simple CSS I am using:

```
QLineEdit, QLineEdit:focus { border: none; }
```

I have tried with different background color through CSS for focus and not-in-focus, it works but I am unable to remove the blue border while in focus. Just to inform, I am working on a Mac.

Comment: Your style sheet works for me in Windows. So does Nikos's solution. Maybe create a small compilable example on your Mac, and if the problem persists, file a bug report.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might get rid of the focus border by setting:

```
QLineEdit.setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)
```

Read the documentation, there are plenty of other Mac specific settings
[WidgetAttribute-enum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

There is rather a similar question too
[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987546/qt4-stylesheets-and-focus-rect)

Comment: Thanks. But in QT5.4, it should be Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect instead of Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also like this way:

```
ui->treeView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0);
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/demos-interview-main-cpp.html