# Adjust width of Focus Rectangle around QLineEdit on Mac

Tags: pyqt5, macos-catalina

When a QLineEdit has focus on a Mac, the Mac automatically puts what seems like a 3px-4px wide Focus Rectangle around it. I read
[Qt4 Stylesheets and Focus Rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987546/qt4-stylesheets-and-focus-rect) but I only want to adjust the width of the Focus Rectangle (to maybe 1px-2 px), not remove it.

[image]

using a for loop for all of my widgets, I also tried

```
if isinstance(widget, QLineEdit):
   widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 1)
```

thinking that the "1" would set the width of the rectangle to 1px, but the code did nothing (my syntax may also be wrong).

Is it possible to set the width in pixels of the focus rectangle on a Mac.

Comment: The second argument of [`setAttribute()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute) is just a bool that (defaults to `True`, which is the "same" as 1 in python), and since the line edit already uses that feature, that won't do nothing. Unfortunately I don't have a recent macOS system, so I cannot provide a valid answer, but I'd suggest you to play around with stylesheets, specifically with the `border` and `outline` (which doesn't always work for all widgets) properties.

Comment: Btw, note that if you only want to set something to all line edits, you should not cycle through *all* widgets: just do `for widget in self.findChildren(QLineEdit):`.

Comment: Will play around with the border and outline as you suggest, but I don't think it is the border that needs adjusting - it seems to be outside the border. And, I'm pretty sure, it's the same on any Mac OS (or at least the last few OS's). thanks for suggestions

Comment: I know that the issue is not the border itself, but since I don't know if the `outline` property will actually work (on Linux it doesn't for QLineEdit), then the only option left is to use `border`, unless you want to use a QStyleProxy (for which you cannot use *any* stylesheet for the target widget, by the way). And, yes, the OS version might change things: OSX/macOS has a long and painful history of issues with Qt (as with many other toolkits) that pop out at each release, as Apple is known to change core aspects that create backward compatibility issues; they simply don't care.

Comment: I suspect you might need to subclass QMacStyle with a subclass that overrides the methods to draw a QLineEdit, call setStyle(new MyMacStyleSubclass) on the qApp object, and have your subclass-method(s) pass a slightly modified QOptionFocusRect parameter up to its superclass method.   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionfocusrect.html

Comment: @JeremyFriesner QMacStyle is not available on Qt5 (it was on Qt4 along with QWindowsStyle from which it inherited from). Qt5 only exposes QCommonStyle and QProxyStyle, so the only option is a QProxyStyle.

Comment: @musicamante yes, that is what I meant, excuse me.